# ros::init(...) throws an error - Windows roscpp

Tags: windows, definition, init, ros

I'm trying to use ros in cpp with Visual Studio 2012. I wrote the publisher and subscriber tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) and first, I configure the project as says in the guide (http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros/hydro/Msvc%20SDK%20Projects).

Then i compiled an linked the publisher, but when I tried to run it, ros::init(argc,argv,"talker") throws an exception... The console says that I ROS_MASTER_URI is not defined but I've got it defined

There are 2 images here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o12m0l38gaxiugi/error1.png  - 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ocdmf0wj6rj0962/error.png

Can anyone helps me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I had the same issue, although I didn't set the `ROS_MASTER_URI` globally.

I managed to get around this specific issue by adding

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

to the debugging environment variables (Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Environment).

However, after implementing the above I got an uncaught exception (`Unhandled exception at 0x768bc41f in ros_demo.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0028f0e4..`).

That went away when I built, compiled and ran the project in release mode (which matched my ROS SDK build).

I got the idea for the release/debug build from [here](http://forum.openscenegraph.org/viewtopic.php?t=12009#53759):

> xstring isn't an OSG specific object, so the error is elsewhere in the
>   3rd party dependency chain.  As I know nothing about your OS and
>   software setup I can't speculate what this might be.
>
> In general though this type of error could well be a linking issue -
>   for instance Visual Studio is hopeless at handling different libs
>   being built debug and release and will crash randomly.

That was fun to discover..

Comment: OMG! Thanks, thanks and thanks again. I was running mad debugging inside the ros libraries (That it was a hell getting a count that they were optimized hahaha). Now it works! :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment :) Yeah, I was also tearing out my hair for quite some time... When I was debugging the ros libraries my node name changed in the debugger from `listener` to `[]^Nlistener` and then `<Bad pointer>` (for no apparent reason of course), which then resulted in `std::bad_alloc`. The only bit of code I could I could get to from the stacktrace was something in `xstring`, which eventually led me to the post I quoted. Anyway, I'm glad I could help!